# Where is the cut-off point for the Dragon's Homecoming Ending?

Tags: sekiro-shadows-die-twice

The Dragon's Homecoming Ending is the most convoluted of all the Sekiro Endings, requiring multiple interactions with all characters, to get specific items in a particular order, so that you have everything you need for the choice after the final boss battle.

The part I'm having trouble with is keeping track of when the cut-off points are for the interactions with Kuro (eavesdropping) and Emma to track down the appropriate information in order to gain access to the Frozen Tears item. For example, in my current playthrough I have completed the Sacred Realm area (Fountainhead Palace, and defeated the Sakura Dragon), I have all the Shinobi tools (though not all upgraded), I have received the rice balls from Kuro, but I have not done anything to gain access to the "investigation" with Emma, or eavesdropped on Kuro yet.

What is the trigger/point of no return for this side-quest to achieve this ending?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, the only hard cut-off for the Return ending is that you must get the rice balls from Kuro before defeating the Divine Dragon. But I would still recommend doing all the steps now because it'll put your mind at ease if you already have the Frozen Tears. The "last" story step necessary for that is to defeat Owl which you have already done in your current playthrough.

Emma is not relevant to the Return ending, and there is only one eavesdrop event which is on the Divine Child after she has ingested the two Viscera items. For the Purification ending when you do need to eavesdrop on Emma and Kuro a bunch of times, you're way past the cut-off as you would have needed to unlock the expanded Hirata memory before killing the Divine Dragon. But again, this is not relevant to the Return ending.